# Stop hovering over element on child element click

Tags: html, css

How can I lose parent's hover state if child is in focus (has been clicked on)? I have a menu arrow (replaced it with OPEN to reduce code) which opens my menu on hover and menu items that focus when I click on them.
After a menu item click I want to be able to lose focus on my parent so the menu could disappear.

I try to avoid any javascript if that's possible and this is my best try...

```
.submenu:not(.submenu ul li a:focus):hover {
    display: block;
}
```

This is my html

```css
.open-submenu:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
}

.submenu {
  display: none;
}

.submenu ul li a:focus {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.submenu:not(.submenu ul li a:focus):hover {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div class="open-submenu">OPEN
      <div class="submenu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

**Edit**

I'm using AngularJS framework on a single page app and clicking on the anchors doesn't reload the page in my case like standard html does.

Comment: but if you click on a link you should also change the page. so the problem should not happen

Comment: @fcalderan I am working with AngularJS on a single page app and my page doesn't refresh on link clicks. Probably should have said that in the description.

Comment: So what should happen to the parent? I suspect `:focus` is probably not correct here.

Comment: @Paulie_D once I click any of the <a> elements and page focuses on that element, .submenu should lose it's hover effect and hide itself (display: none). :focus was my go at making the menu hide.

Comment: Yeah, i don't think you can do that since, at least in your demo, you're still hovering the parent and that will take precendence over anything else. - Perhaps `:target`...but I'm not sure on that one.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.submenu:hover ul li:active,
.submenu:hover ul li:active ~ li {
  display: none;
}
```

You can try with this but not sure if you can provide any links in href since it is using display none.

If it doesn't work then you may need to use jQuery/javascript to achieve the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The solution wold be `:not(:focus-within)`, ***IF*** the click event would precede the click event of the anchors. The click event is thus never dispatched and you menu is not working. I'm afraid, you cannot go without JS in that case.

```css
.open-submenu:hover .submenu:not(:focus-within) {
  display: block;
}

.submenu {
  display: none;
}

.submenu ul li a:focus {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div class="open-submenu">OPEN
      <div class="submenu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Yeah, I've already tried that and it would have been a good solution if it worked on any IE browser.